# Unable to author block in slot, can_author_with returned: spec_name does not match. Probably a node update is required!

Tags: frontier-node-template

I am getting this error after trying to create a new blockchain (named newchain) copying another one I had working for many years (named oldchain).
I cleaned the db (with the purge-chain command), changed the chain id, chain name, and even the spec_version. But when starting a new node with the newchain I get this message:

```
Unable to author block in slot 283224808,. `can_author_with` returned: `spec_name` does not match `newchain-node` vs `oldchain-node` Probably a node update is required!
```

I can't understand where the "oldchain-node" comes from. Since it does not appear in any part of the code, the docker image and container where created from scratch, and the db was cleaned.

The command I use to start the node is:

```
./target/release/frontier-template-node --chain newchain.json --validator --rpc-port 8334 --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --node-key="$nodeK" --rpc-methods=Unsafe --rpc-external --rpc-cors=all --ws-external --name newchain --bootnodes /ip4/xx.xx.xx.xx/tcp/30333/p2p/$nodeId
```

The IP of the bootnode matches the IP of the newchain node, and so does the nodeId

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to regenerate the chain spec with this command:

```
./target/release/frontier-template-node build-spec --disable-default-bootnode > new-chainspec.json
```